# Rails migration assumes a relationship where there is none

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-migrations

I have a Rails 3.1 app with a `User` model and a `Venue` model. These two models have a HABTM relationship - A user may manage many venues and a venue may be managed by many users.

I'd like users to be able to select a default venue so I'm trying to add a `default_venue_id` attribute to `User` with the following migration:

```
class AddDefaultVenueIdToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :default_venue_id, :integer
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :default_venue_id
  end
end
```

The problem is that when I run that migration against my PostgreSQL database, it's assuming that `default_venue_id` is the foreign key for a relationship with the non-existent `default_venues` table and throws the following error:

```
PGError: ERROR:  relation "default_venues" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("default_venue_id") REFERENCES "default_venues" ("id")
```

Should I be doing something to tell the database that I'm not trying to create a relationship or am I going about this the wrong way?

**Edit:** I've just realised that another developer who worked on the project added the [schema_plus](https://github.com/lomba/schema_plus) gem which automatically defines constraints for columns ending in `_id`

That explains why I've never run into this behaviour before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the Models as well to diagnose this problem.

However with that being said, I think that if you are using `HABTM` associations here it might be a good idea to take a look at a has many through relationship. example: `VenueManagement` which would have your `user_id` and `venue_id`. That way you could handle extra attributes on the association where it makes sense, like a default flag.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You're right, has many through would be much more suitable in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since Rails seems to pick up on the _id part of the tag and tries linking it to a table, the easy solution to this is to try name it differently as convention says a field with _id links to a table.

An example of which could be
 `:default_id_for_venue`, or just `:defualt_venue`

Comment: Thanks, I suspected it may be down to the _id but it's not something I've ever run into before.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Rails not to link to a table? A not-so-easy solution to this? e.g. an owner_id that is always a user id.